# Count rows in a table based on a DATE field

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, query, subquery

I have a table with 3 columns (order_id, client_id, date_added).
The content would look something like this:

```
order_id | client_id  | date_added
-----------------------------------
14152    | NA4156     | 2019-03-01
14153    | EA4656     | 2019-03-02
14154    | EA4656     | 2019-03-02
14155    | CA4456     | 2019-03-03
14156    | DA4556     | 2019-03-03
14157    | EA4656     | 2019-03-03
14158    | FA4756     | 2019-03-06
14159    | GA4856     | 2019-03-06
```

and so on.
As you can see on a certain day there might be no entries.

I am trying to obtain the following result:

```
date       | no_of_rows
-----------------------------
2019-03-01 | 1
2019-03-02 | 2
2019-03-03 | 4
2019-03-04 | 4
2019-03-05 | 4
2019-03-06 | 6
```

I understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query) how to generate all dates that I am looking for, but I am not sure now how to count the unique clients based on **client_id** for each date.

At the moment I am doing this step by step and moving the data into an Excel and processing it from there using the query below:

get unique number of clients registered until and including 2019-03-01

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM clients WHERE date_added < '2019-03-02' GROUP BY client_id
```

get unique number of clients registered until and including 2019-03-02

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) FROM clients WHERE date_added < '2019-03-03' GROUP BY client_id
```

and so on.

But this method seems to be a little bit exhaustive and I am pretty sure there is a way to do it in a single query, but not sure where to start from.

Comment: Specify your MySQL version. *how to count the unique clients based on client_id for each date.* `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT client_id)`

Comment: @Akinathe Mysql Version is 5.5.50

Comment: `SELECT t1.date, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.client_id) FROM (subquery which generates dates list) t1, clients t2 WHERE t1.date >= t2.date GROUP BY t1.date`

Answer (score 1):

You have to utilise the [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) function along with the [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) function along the lines of

```
SELECT
 date_added AS Date,
 COUNT(Client_ID ) AS no_of_rows 
FROM CLIENTS
GROUP BY date_added  
ORDER BY date_added;
```

Using the above produces output in the form of

```
Date        no_of_rows
2019-03-01  1
2019-03-02  2
2019-03-03  3
2019-03-06  2
```

As an aside it is generally a good idea not to name a column with the name of a datatype i.e I would probably call the Data column in the result ClientDate.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call your table **ORDERS**. As mentioned in your question, for a certain day there might not be any orders but in your final report, even those days should also be present.

To get the desired output we must combine [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query), LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY and COUNT.

**Step 1** : Create a view called *V_DATES* :

```
create view V_DATES
as
select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
from (
        select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
        union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 
        union select 8 union select 9
) t0,
(
        select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
        union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 
        union select 8 union select 9
) t1,
(
        select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
        union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 
        union select 8 union select 9
) t2,
(
        select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
        union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 
        union select 8 union select 9
) t3,
(
        select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 
        union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 
        union select 8 union select 9
) t4
```

**Step 2:** Execute the following query to get your desired output

```
select vd.selected_date, count(distinct c.client_id)
from V_DATES vd
left outer join CLIENTS c
on vd.selected_date = c.date_added
where vd.selected_date between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-06'
group by vd.selected_date;
```